# Execute php with onclick in d3

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js

I am working with a d3 scatterplot that displays papers as dots on the graph. It is connected to a database with multiple tables. What I want to do is when I *click* on one of the dots on the graph I want the papers that it cites to appear on the graph. The citations table in the database is as follows- where ID_from is the list of paper IDs and ID_to are the IDs of papers that a paper cites:

```
ID_from    ID_to
1           12
1           40
2           7
3           2
3           50
3           N
...
N           13
```

So for example if I clicked on paper ID 3 I want paper 2,50 AND N to appear as dots on the graph. 
I have a very vague idea of how this should work that is, to execute the php function within the onClick function? But my question is how can this be done? And am I able to use the same php script with other queries defined in it? 
Here is my php script connecting to the database with other queries I need executed NOT ON CLICK.

```
<?php
$username = "xxx"; 
$password = "";   
$host = "xxx";
$database="xxx";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

$data = array(
'query1Results' => array(),
'query2Results' => array()
);

$myquery = "SELECT  `ID`, `TITLE`, `YEAR`,`In_library` FROM  `papers` where In_library = 1";

$query1 = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query1 ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query1); $x++) {
    $data['query1Results'][] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
}

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT `ID_to`, count(*) as `counter` from `citations` group by `ID_to` DESC");

if ( ! $query2 ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query2); $x++) {
    $data['query2Results'][] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);


?>
```

I am also having a complete blank on what the query would be (I am very new to sql) and am confusing myself at variable IDs

Thanks for feedback in advance

EDIT: The following is how my database is structured
Papers table:

```
ID   TITLE   YEAR   IN_LIBRARY
ID1  TITLE1  YEAR     1
ID2   TITLE2  YEAR    0
```

Citations table (ex above):

```
ID_from    ID_to
```

AUTHORS TABLE:

```
ID    AUTHOR
1     AUTHOR1
1     AUTHOR1.2
2     AUTHOR2
3     AUTHOR3
3     AUTHOR3.1
3     AUTHOR3.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve executing the PHP with a jQuery ajax call wrapped in a .click() handler.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

https://api.jquery.com/click/

If you factored the PHP correctly you should be able to use the same file for any of the dots point being clicked on.

```
<?php

// Grab posted variables
$fromID = $_POST['fromID']; // From what you explained this will always be a single value.
$toID = $_POST['toID']; // From what you explained this will be an array, you could accomplish this easily by crating a hidded input for each value of the toID on the scatterplot dot I have given an example of this code below
$toID = join(',',$toID); 

/*
    <input type="hidden" name="toID[]" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="toID[]" value="50">
    <input type="hidden" name="toID[]" value="N">
*/

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `citations` WHERE `ID_from` = {$toID} AND `ID_to` IN {$toID}");

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}else{
    // You will then need to return the HTML to the browser for the ajax call to create the new dots on the scatter plot
    $html="html here"
    $html.= "next line of html"
    echo $html;
}




// I would also consider using mysqli or mysql pdo
// Hope this helps

?>
```

Here are starting places for mysqli and mysql PDO

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: please see above where I added the structure of my database! thank you

Comment: John, I'm just leaving work, sorry didn't see this earlier I will post some help later tonight or early in the morning.

Comment: John, I updated my answer to assist you further. Thanks!